# "LSI Adapter, SAS 3000 Series" - How can I find the specific model?

Tags: windows-server-2008, storage, hardware-raid, lsi

I'm having trouble finding documentation on this RAID controller.  The Windows system details aren't very specific.  It just says `LSI Adapter, SAS 3000 series, 8-port with 1068E`.

The server is an HP Z800.

Here is a screenshot of the device manager:

[image]

---

I initially installed the Intel RST software, but it shows no attached drives.

I then installed the MegaRAID Manager and was able to see the drives.

---

This is a VM host with multiple company VMs, so I don't want to shut it down just to get the exact model of the card (if it's even visible).  **How can I find out the exact model of the controller without physical access?** What other information can I provide?

---

EDIT: According to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/404991/are-all-sas-drives-hot-swappable), it looks like SAS is inherently (intended to be) hot swappable.  So I've reworded the question.

Comment: Please add information about your environment. I guess you are running this on Win Server with HyperV, but you need to make this clear.

Comment: I added a Windows tag, but I don't think the fact that it's a hyper-v host is really relevant to the question itself so I didn't add that.

Comment: No, HyperV in itself is not important , the Windows part is :)

Comment: If it's a server buy from a major brand, like dell, hp or ibm in example, a model number can tell us the exact controller model too, as system build are documented.

Comment: I have added the server model to the post.  Sorry I didn't think to include that originally, seems obvious :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the adapter hardware details you should be able to find the PCI vendor and device ID: in *Device Manager*, open the controller's *Properties*, go to *Details* and select *Hardware IDs*.

Since the

```
LSI Adapter, SAS 3000 series, 8-port with 1068
```

is also a common, generic *virtual* adapter you have to make sure that you're doing this on the hypervisor, not inside a guest.

Edit:

This caught my eye only on second reading: *installed the Intel RST software* can't work, you need LSI MegaRAID software for LSI RAID hardware. HPE surely's got it posted on the support site.

Edit2:

From the [quickspecs](http://www.hp.com/canada/products/landing/workstations/files/13278_na.pdf):

```
Integrated SAS controller
...
SAS Processor     LSISAS1068E
```

Comment: That's weird, this is definitely the physical host (unless there are VMs on a VM...).  I edited the original post to include a screenshot of the device manager.

Comment: Well, the model devices chosen for virtual hardware are those that are quite common, have mature drivers and are well-documented. It should be the *1068E* model (the mezzanine variant of the *1068*).

Comment: Pointing out the intel thing was an edit after your post. It was an attempt to show that the LSI device was not virtual, but it was a poor attempt. I've reworded the question again a bit.

Comment: I would have assumed the model would start with a 3, being a "3000 series"?  For instance: https://www.amazon.com/Logic-Controller-Card-Sas3081E-R-Minisas/dp/B000RHDVK2

Comment: LSI model numbers never made much sense to me - I found the quickspecs and added that to the answer above.